# Where should I put my dart files if they are the server side files of restful api providers?

Tags: dart, project-structure, dart-pub

I'm trying to use [start](https://github.com/lvivski/start) to write some restful apis for clients.

The content is looking like:

```dart
import 'package:start/start.dart';
import 'myfile1.dart';
import 'myfile2.dart';
import 'myfile3.dart';
import 'myfile4.dart';

void main() {
start(public: 'web', port: 3000).then((Server app) {
    app.get('/').listen((request) {
      request.response
        .send('Hello, dart');
    });
    app.get('/aaa').listen(...);
    app.get('/bbb').listen(...);
    app.get('/ccc').listen(...);
    app.get('/ddd').listen(...);
  });
}
```

Notice there are also some other dart files `myfileN.dart` in the same dir.

Where should I put them?

According to the [dart project layout](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html), there are several entry points:

```
bin
lib
web
example
test
```

But I don't know where should I put my dart files. Since this is not a library, it's just an server-side application, and is not a web app, not a test, not an example, and not a command-line script.

I think there should be a `src` to put my files, but there is not. How to solve this problem? Doesn't the standard layout doesn't design well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many applications use third-party software.

Third-party software often organized as `pluggable functionality`.

Pluggable functionality often implemented not as independent executables but as `linked libraries`.

Also when you wrote `application` then you often divide it on `different functionality`.

The best way in this case (in `Dart`) put `different functionality` in `different libraries`.
This simplify your life when you will be `testing` and `maintain` your application.

By convention libraries in Dart resides in `'lib'` directory.
Also `implementation` of libraries by convention must be located in `'lib/src'` directory.

There may also be other possible explanations for this need.
I just tried explain it to you `as simple as possible`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `src` within `lib` and put your files there.

If the files are executable, you can put them inside `bin`, or within a directory inside `bin`.

See the [package layout conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) for details.